# I can't change the screen with MDFlatButton in a loop

Tags: python, button, kivy, kivymd, flatbutton

I can't change screen by the buttons that I define in a for loop and it shows this error:
AttributeError: type object 'ScreenManager' has no attribute 'manager'
I want to define it in the .py file because it must be in the for loop to create a button for each item.
you can find the code below.
please assist

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty,StringProperty
from kivymd.uix.list import MDList,OneLineListItem,TwoLineListItem
from kivymd.uix.button import MDFlatButton
#from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
#import json
from kivy.storage.jsonstore import JsonStore
from kivy.clock import Clock,mainthread
import sys
import os.path
import json

file = sys.argv[0]
foldername =os.path.dirname(file)

store = JsonStore(foldername+"/data.json")

screen_helper = """
ScreenManager:

    MainScreen: 
    AddScreen: 
    PerScreen: 
    TripDetail:

<MainScreen>:
    name:  'Main'
    MDRectangleFlatButton:
        text: 'add new'
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5,'center_y':0.5}
        on_press: root.manager.current = 'Add'
    MDRectangleFlatButton:
        text: 'pervius cal'
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5,'center_y':0.2}
        on_press: root.manager.current = 'Per'
<AddScreen>:
    id: addScreen
    name: 'Add'
    MDLabel:
        text: 'add new'
        halign: 'center'
        pos_hint:{'center_x':0.5,'center_y':0.9}
    MDRectangleFlatButton:
        text: 'back'
        pos_hint:{'center_x':0.5,'center_y':0.1}
        on_press: root.manager.current = 'Main'
    MDTextField:
        id: addNewCal
        hint_text: "Enter cal name:"
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5,'center_y':0.6}
        size_hint_x: None
        width:300
    MDRectangleFlatButton:
        text: 'save'
        pos_hint:{'center_x':0.5,'center_y':0.4}
        on_press: root.save()
<PerScreen>:
    name: 'Per'
    ScrollView:
        size_hint_y:None
        height: 400
        MDList:
            id: tripList
    MDLabel:
        text: 'pervius cal'
        halign: 'center'
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.3,'center_y':0.9}
    MDRectangleFlatButton:
        text: 'back'
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.7,'center_y':0.9}
        on_press: root.manager.current = 'Main'
<TripDetail>:
    name: 'TripDetail'
    MDLabel:
        text: 'test'
"""

class MainScreen(Screen):
    pass

class AddScreen(Screen):
    screenManager = ObjectProperty(None)
    def save(self):
        calName = self.ids.addNewCal.text
        trip = {"tripname":calName,"persons":[],"sumCost": "0","personCost":[]}
        with open(foldername+"/data.json","r") as f:
            data = json.load(f)
            data["trips"].append(trip)
        with open(foldername+"/data.json","w") as f:
            json.dump(data,f,indent = 2)
        print(calName)

    pass

class PerScreen(Screen):
    
    @mainthread

    def on_enter(self, *args):
        """Event fired when the screen is displayed: the entering animation is
        complete."""
        
        def on_enter(interval):
            with open(foldername+"/data.json","r") as f:
                data = json.load(f)
                trip = data["trips"]
            self.ids.tripList.clear_widgets()
                
            **for i in range(len(trip)):
                self.ids.tripList.add_widget(MDFlatButton(text=trip[i]["tripname"],on_press = showTrip))
        def showTrip(self,*args):
            ScreenManager.manager.current = 'TripDetail'**
    
            

        Clock.schedule_once(on_enter)
class TripDetail(Screen):
    pass

sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(MainScreen(name='Main'))
sm.add_widget(AddScreen(name='Add'))
sm.add_widget(PerScreen(name='Per'))
sm.add_widget(TripDetail(name='TripDetail'))


class DongApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        screen = Builder.load_string(screen_helper)
        return screen  
        
    def showTrip(self):
        self.sm.current = 'TripDetail'


DongApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message is telling you what you are doing wrong. The `ScreenManager` class has no `manager`attribute. You need to set the `current` attribute of the `ScreenManager` instance, which you get from the `MDApp`.

Try changing:

```
ScreenManager.manager.current = 'TripDetail'
```

to:

```
MDApp.get_running_app().root.current = 'TripDetail'
```

Comment: thanks a lot it resolved,
I have one another question that how can I pass a value. for example I want to pass the button text and put it in the label text of the new screen.

Comment: You can use the [get_screen()](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.screenmanager.html#kivy.uix.screenmanager.ScreenManager.get_screen) method to access any `Screen`, then use `ids` defined for that `Screen` to access any `Label`.